# How to do this in ADO.NET Entities Framework

Tags: .net, linq, entity-framework, c#-3.0

I have a table called BlogPost which has a 1-to-many relationship with the Comment table.  (In Comment, there's a foreign key BlogPostId.)

Now I want to retrieve all posts as well as the latest comments of each post.  I've tried with s/t like below but it doesn't work.

```
from r in Db.BlogPost
select new {Post = r, LatestComment = r.Comments.Last()};
```

The error message sounds like Last() is not a supported operator by EF.  Is there any way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about r.Comments.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Id).FirstOrDefault()
?

Essentially, order it (most recent first), and then take the first?